# Check Recyclerview empty or not with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have made a Recyclerview in fragment with firebase realtime database and I want check the recyclerview is empty or not how can I access bookadapter.itemcount in fun Datasnapshot of addValueEventlistner
and have also added some condition in adapter to remove some item in Recyclerview but unable to check recyclerview is empty or not so,please solve my problem.

Books.kt

```
 private fun showbooks() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            try {
                booklist.clear()
                for (item in snapshot.children) {
                    val bookid = item.child("BookId").value.toString()
                    val bookname = item.child("BookName").value.toString()
                    val bookpublication = item.child("BookPublication").value.toString()
                    val bookdept = item.child("Department").value.toString()
                    val bookimage = item.child("BookImage").value.toString()
                    val bookyear = item.child("BookYear").value.toString()
                    val userid = item.child("UserUID").value.toString()
                    val date = item.child("Date").value.toString()
                    RedeleteBook(date, bookimage, bookid)
                    booklist.add(
                        Booksmodel(
                            bookid,
                            bookimage,
                            bookname,
                            bookdept,
                            bookpublication,
                            bookyear,
                            userid,
                        )
                    )
                    bookadapter =
                        bookadapter(
                            booklist,
                            this@Books
                        )
                    bookadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    bookrecyclerView.adapter =
                        bookadapter
                    bookprogressbar.visibility =
                        View.GONE
                    
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                bookprogressbar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "please check connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            bookprogressbar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    })
```

bookadapter.kt

```
package com.bookqueen.bookqueen.adapter

class bookadapter(
private var booklist: ArrayList<Booksmodel>,
private val itemClickListener: OnBookItemClicklistner
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<bookadapter.bookholder>() {

var searchText: String = ""


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): bookholder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.singlebook, parent, false)
    return bookholder(view)
}

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
fun filterlist(filterlist: ArrayList<Booksmodel>, searchText: String) {
    booklist = filterlist
    this.searchText = searchText
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: bookholder, position: Int) {
    val view = booklist[position]

    holder.bind(view, itemClickListener)


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    Log.d("Booksize",(booklist.size.toString()))
    return if (booklist.size == 0) 0 else booklist.size
}

inner class bookholder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val bookname: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.recbooknametxt)
    val bookpublication = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recbookpubtxt)
    val bookdept = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recbookdepttxt)
    val bookimage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.recbookimg)
    val bookview = view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.bookcardView)

 

    fun bind(book: Booksmodel, clicklistner: OnBookItemClicklistner) {

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        Mycollege.college(object : Mycollege.Mycallback {
            override fun onCallback(value: String) {
                Log.d("Mycoolege", value)
                database.getReference("Users").child(book.UserUID.toString())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.value != null) {
                                val usercollege = snapshot.child("College").value.toString()

                                if (usercollege == value) {

                                    if (searchText.isNotBlank()) {
                                        val highlightedText = book.BookName!!.replace(
                                            searchText,
                                            "<font color='red'>$searchText</font>",
                                            true
                                        )
                                        bookname.text =
                                            HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                                                highlightedText,
                                                HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
                                            )
                                    } else {
                                        bookname.text = book.BookName
                                    }
                                    //bookname.text=book.BookName
                                    bookpublication.text = book.BookPublication
                                    bookdept.text = book.Department
                                    Picasso.get().load(book.BookImage)
                                        .error(R.drawable.ic_action_book)
                                        .into(bookimage)
                                } else {
                                    booklist.remove(book)
                                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                                   
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                        }
                    })
            }
        })


        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clicklistner.onBookItemclick(book)
        }
    }

}

interface OnBookItemClicklistner {
    fun onBookItemclick(books: Booksmodel)
}

}
```

Comment: probably a bad idea to be making a new `bookadapter` every time the data changes, you just need one adapter and then you can always change the data it has. also you really don't need to be making a new adapter in a for loop

Comment: yes I don't know how I add these but I solve my problem

Comment: So you need to check if your adapter is empty? Basically, if it contains elements or not?